# How to override any Model of vendor folder in laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, overriding

I am using MongoDB as database so I need to change model of package `tzsk\payu` as using original is giving me following error
`Call to a member function prepare() on null`
I tried excluding original model and overriding using composer it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be if the [package](https://github.com/tzsk/payu) offered the option to use a custom model, like [Passport is doing](https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport#overriding-default-models).

As far as I can see, there does not seem to be a way to do that. Thus you'd need to fork the package and edit the Model yourself.

Comment: Yes it doesn't offer that...
can you please explain what is ** fork the package ** as I'm new to this. Thanks